# Safe macro keys for a macro keyboard?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard, macros, autohotkey

I bought a [24 macro keyboard from xkeys](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MB780E). I'm using it to to have unique keys that don't trigger anything on windows or any apps I use. This way I can easily make autohotkey profiles to run macros.

What are some good key combinations to use here? (e.g. Numpad+ modifier keys)

Comment: If AHK can capture them, use HID values that are beyond anything any app uses.

Comment: is there some programming application to test what keys are capturable by autohotkey? Do I have to delve into lua scripting as well or no?

Comment: Couldn't actually tell you; I've never actually used AHK. I'm just speaking from my other-OS experience.

Comment: tom scotts video answered alot of questions i had regarding safekeys here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U

Answer (score 1):

I bound all my keys using my modifiers + F13 to F24 keys. Originally, I had used modifiers+ numpad, didn't work that well.

[image]

Xkeys has a function area for keys like F13 to F24, and tells which one are standalone hardware compatability or requires software:

- F13 to F24 can be written on hardware
- Joystick command keys (airflight, etc) can be written to hardware

[image]

I run a cross-platform application called Phrase-Express as well, and this also lets you program F13 to F24 keys.

I was able successfully able to assign all modifiers with F13 to F24 keys (some combination of CTRL, SHIFT, ALT). This means I can have keys like:

- F13
- CTRL+F13
- CTRL+ALT+F13
- CTRL+SHIFT+F13
- CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F13
- ALT+F13
- ALT+SHIFT+F13
- SHIFT+F13

**leading to a possible combination of 8 * 12 = 96 unique cross-OS compatible hardware based keys.**

Comment: **Unique keys** that don't trigger anything on windows or any apps: **F13-F24**. If the keyboard program is using an editable file (e.g. XML) to store settings, you can try editing this file by replacing your settings with those keys (F13-F24, after backing up the original file).

Answer (score 1):

Are these key reassignments done using the custom xkey software that comes with the keypad?

I've wondered about the setup for these keypads before and whether or not you would be able to use Joy1 through Joy32 (joystick button assignments).

The joystick buttons are supported by AutoHotkey as inputs and wouldn't override any other keyboard combos, but if the custom software doesn't allow you to map to those combinations then you would be out of luck.

I haven't seen any other posts on the setup for these keypad entries so curious what would actually work or not.

Comment: hmmm i never thought about joypad. As far as I know, only xbox controller drivers work natively with windows (PS4 does not). I will have to test this out :)